# Excel - conditional formatting between columns in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Hi as you can see from the attached image I have a very simple pivot table which shows for each category value per year
[image: simple table]

I want to apply conditional formatting which will compare values between columns and add up and down arrows so I have the final result something like this

[image: finall result]
where of course the first column will not have any arrows but second (2015) will have arrows depending on the simple formula 
value (previous column) > value (current column) => green arrow, else red

I've tried to google, there are many tutorials for conditional formatting between two columns in a non-pivot table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to record an example for you to work with:

[image]

Repeat for other columns